# Running Websocket on remote server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-websockets

I Have a problem with laravel websockets .

I'm trying to run websocket server using Artisan call like this :

```
Artisan::call('websockets:serve');
```

but it didn't work (returned request timeout) knowing that it works correctly when i run :

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

Here are some illustrations :

[image]
[image]

still like that then give me request timeout .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

websocket:serve is trying to start a long running process. I'm not sure I understand the context in which you are trying to call Artisan::call('websockets:serve');, but if that is behind an http session, the http session is likely timing out and the websocket process is ending.